# Writing to file in Java

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

First things first, I am a novice when it comes to Java. I have set myself a little project and I am currently stuck. I am trying to write to a file that already exists, but it just overwrites it. I am trying to replace the line that contains 'maxBooks'.

Here is the code than I am using:

```
FileWriter writeFile = new FileWriter(fileLocation);
            BufferedReader readLines = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileLocation));
            BufferedWriter writeLines = new BufferedWriter(writeFile);

            System.out.println("\n-----File Begin-----");

            while((finalLines = readLines.readLine()) != null){

                if(finalLines.contains("maxBooks")){
                    writeLines.newLine();
                    writeLines.write(finalLines);

                    System.out.println("This is the if statement");
                    System.out.println(finalLines);
                } else {
                    fileLines.add(new String(finalLines));
                    System.out.println("This is the else statement");
                    System.out.println(finalLines);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("------File End------");
```

Please bear in mind that I have left out the try and catch. Please let me know how I can edit the text file. Let me know if you need any more info

Thanks :)

EDIT

Sorry, I should clarify. I am just trying to edit 1 line that is in the test file, not the whole text file.

FINAL CODE:

```
FileWriter writeFile = new FileWriter(fileLocation + ".tmp", true);
            BufferedWriter writeLines = new BufferedWriter(writeFile);

            BufferedReader readLines = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileLocation));


            System.out.println("\n-----File Begin-----");

            while((finalLines = readLines.readLine()) != null){

                if(finalLines.contains("maxBooks")){
                    writeLines.write("maxBooks = " + maxBooks);
                    writeLines.newLine();

                    System.out.println("This is the if statement");
                    System.out.println(finalLines);
                } else {
                    fileLines.add(new String(finalLines));
                    System.out.println("This is the else statement");
                    writeLines.write(finalLines);
                    writeLines.newLine();
                }
            }

            System.out.println("------File End------");

            file2.renameTo(file);

            writeLines.close();
```

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?  If you're using 7, you can make use of Java.NIO for some of this.

Comment: _I am trying to write to a file that already exists, but it just overwrites it_ , not clear what you mean with this (the code does what it does). Maybe give a short example of input, what you expect and what you get.

Comment: try with  FileWriter writeFile = new FileWriter(fileLocation, true);

Comment: PeterMmm, I need to edit just 1 line in the text file. So say the original text file contains 2 lines: maxBooks = 2, and totalBooks = 5. I want to just edit the first line (maxBooks = 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You overwrite the file you try to read, which is bad practice. Write to a new file, then rename to the original file.

Comment: Thanks @fge, it worked like a dream, my updated code is in my question. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

you read and write on the same `fileLocation` you're supposed to give two differend locations;

goes something like this

```
//define newLocation as string that contain path for new file to be written    
FileWriter writeFile = new FileWriter(newLocation);
                BufferedReader readLines = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileLocation));
                BufferedWriter writeLines = new BufferedWriter(writeFile);
```